# When are FAQs important for a website?

Tags: usability, faq

We have an online product similar to Muzli colors and is targeted for limited/internal audience. So wanted to ask if we should provide FAQs with such limited functionality. Below are two main actions that a user can perform on our site:

1. We have various layouts and the user can change colors by a universal color palette similar to Muzli.
2. User can also select and download the layouts. They can also share these layouts with internal peers.

Just for more context, this website is only for our organization and can be accessed from our internal portal.

I really appreciate if anyone can share UX guidelines for the use of FAQs.

[The palette](https://colors.muz.li/palette/e06f1f/9d5716/e0a21f/e03e1f/9d2b16):
[image: palette]

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest, a FAQ isn't necessary, though personally, I would say that why not **but**:

- The FAQ should be short, consisting only of the most important questions
- Each Q&A should consist of only one of two sentences (whith an eventual link to a more complete page)

### One solution

As [mentionned](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/140469/139671) by Johannes, FAQs contain information that is usually unsorted, so a **search bar** would fix the issue. **But**, why creating a whole new page with a search bar, when your website already have a global search bar ? The idea here is to include the FAQs directly into the search bar, as some sort of auto-completion/research suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and research, I can tell you that F.A.Q. should not exist. The information that the user learns from those F.A.Q. should be evenly distributed and communicated in their matching sections in the system. I always work with a content writer to make sure that answers to common questions will be written where the user is more likely to look for them.

Comment: ...on the other hand, there's no real danger in duplicating information availability, as long as it can be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Never.

FAQs contain information that is usually unsorted, that requires context to answer and that is outside the structure you used to educate the user in the first place.

When you create user information, you follow a certain structure, for example:

1. what kind of software/machine/system is it?
2. what can you do with it?
3. what input data/material is expected?
4. How can this data/material be manipulated and what are the effects of my actions?
5. what output is produced? How can I tell if my actions have been successful?

or any other structure, whatever fits your users' needs. This holds across all kinds of media, be it a user manual, a tutorial video or a course.

If questions are actually asked frequently, it means that this knowledge is either not included in your user information, is not understandable or is too difficult to find. **Fix this first**.